# File pointer in C# | How to access multiple segments of a large file

Tags: c#, file, pointers, handle

I have a large file, want to keep 5-6 pointer which divides the file in chunks and gives faster access to any part. Is is possible to achieve in c#.

Comment: What analysis have you done to prove that access time is a problem?

Comment: Do you mean e.g. the offsets of blocks of data that you can only determine by parsing the whole file, such as the 100,000th line or a certain XML element?

Comment: I have a huge xml file and there are elements around 5 million, at request i want to display a chunk say 1000 elements in useful format in reverse order. Processing the entire file every time is not good idea. I thought of putting my own elements in the file at intervals (sort of bookmarking) but we decided not to touch original xml file.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Memory-Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) is the closest option to do what you want to do, without much hardwork on your side.

**Edit** : I assumed you are on .NET 4.0 since this is not available in earlier framework versions. [Nice article talking about efficiency you are looking for](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/salvapatuel/archive/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4.aspx)

Comment: Forgot to mention that it is a XML file and want to parse it in useful way. Not sure it memory map files will help as I want to know which element I am on.